# Problem with 2 PPTP VPN connections

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-10.10, pptp

I have a problem with my network-manager in Ubuntu 10.10.

When I dial one of my VPN connections, my other VPN connections be disabled and I can't use them!

I tried to restart network-manager and gnome-panel, but it does't seem to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

you need to plan your routing carefully if you are to use 2 vpn connection at one time. usually connection to one vpn means that it will be set as a default gateway.

please explain more on your configuration and let us help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of [PPTP Passthrough](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/07/28/pptp-passthrough/). What you are actually describing is VPN passthrough where the router allows outbound VPN connections. The reason only one connection is allowed is explained in this article called [Multiple VPN Connections – Why It Isn’t Possible](http://think-like-a-computer.com/2011/08/09/multiple-vpn-connections/). It's a good read!